# combobox Selected Text changed event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code. After adding data through `DataSource`, The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not firing.

```
try
{
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

    //comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    comboBox1.ResetText();

    Cn.Open();
    SqlCommand Cd = new SqlCommand("Select Distinct Mobile From Client_Details Where Branch = '" + label2.Text + "'", Cn);
    SqlDataReader da = Cd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Mobile", typeof(string));
    dt.Load(da);
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Mobile";
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = "<Select>";
}
catch
{

}
finally
{
    Cn.Close();
    Clear();
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Label CBSL = new Label();
    //string CBSL = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (comboBox9.Text == "Client")
    {
        Update_Read_Client();
    }
    else if (comboBox9.Text == "Customer")
    {
        Update_Read();
    }
}
```

1. It selects the first value again and again.
2. I had tried DropDownStye = DropDownList., But it become dormant. No values is added.
3. Any help to resolve my problem.

Comment: You're checking comboBox**9** instead of comboBox**1** inside the event handler.

Comment: Thanks., But I am using the combobox1 selected value in the function update_Read_Client() & Update_Read() for a select query

Comment: are you sure there is a mobile with name <Select> in your dataSource?

Comment: No ., That was a defined first text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have "< Select >" item saved in your database. Also, when using `DataTable` it's easier to fill it using `SqlDataAdapter`. You should also use parameters instead of string concat when you're writing your query like this and `using` keyword closes your connection automatically when you're done using it. I'd write it like this probably:

```
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT DISTINCT Mobile
                        FROM Client_Details
                        WHERE Branch = @Branch";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", label2.Text);

    try
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Mobile", typeof(string));

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Mobile"] = "<Select>";                    
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Mobile";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "<Select>";
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was breaking my head and was thinking to truncate the database and designing it some other way. Your piece of code saved me. This was the most clear solution., I had ever seen. Thank you so much.